#5333 prescient answers
For #5333 Difference between stream cipher and block cipher
the question and accepted answer are dated Nov 11 '12 but two other answers and a bunch of comments are dated Sep 22 '12 -- at least as displayed to me. How can, should or did this happen? Is it actually a bug?
To add to the weirdness, TNT (cable TV channel) just showed the movie "Minority Report" !

To add to the weirdness… – No need to worry. ;)

A question was asked in September 2012 (Why is there a strong distinction between stream and block ciphers?). This question was asked in November 2012. The two were determined to be similar enough to be considered duplicates, so the better was kept and the other, which was older, was merged into the one in question. 
